# Android SQLite Database update table when update app

Tags: android, sqlite, upgrade, updates

I have situation :

In the newer version of the app i will add another column to the SQLite table. I need to make this change take effect when application is updating and do not lose data from database (via recreating with new structure).

May be in onUpgrade start my SQL Update scripts? How to do it correctly?

Comment: Just use `Alter Table` sql command and add new column. it's not effect to your data. Do it inside `onUpgrade(.....)`

Comment: I know sql script, but can i safely do it in the onUpgrade? Which is standard solution fot this task?

Comment: What you expect then?  This is the only one and standard way.

Comment: ok, thanks for response

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to upgrade your database version in `onCreate()` and then use `onUpgrade()`. Like this:

```
public YouSQLiteHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, Constants.DATABASE_NAME, null, Constants.DATABASE_VERSION); --> 1 to 2 for example


}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


    addNewColumnTable();
}
```

When you change your database version, Android automatically call `onUpgrade()` and your database will be updated with all the changes that you put in `onUpgrade()` when the user update the app